# Current transformer schematic diagram

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

How can I draw the below schematic diagram in latex.

[image]

Comment: You might also look at the circuitikz package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the TeX.SE. The drawing is done with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) for the neibie with `LaTeX`.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\blindenumerate[2]
\blindtext[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,417); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 417

%Shape: Inductor (Air Core) [id:dp5208885195945387] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (147.6,108) -- (147.6,128.88) .. controls (138.79,129.18) and (131.27,132.08) .. (128.64,136.18) .. controls (126.01,140.28) and (128.81,144.75) .. (135.69,147.44) .. controls (141.06,149.51) and (148,150.36) .. (154.74,149.76) .. controls (157.37,149.76) and (159.5,148.72) .. (159.5,147.44) .. controls (159.5,146.16) and (157.37,145.12) .. (154.74,145.12) .. controls (148,144.52) and (141.06,145.37) .. (135.69,147.44) .. controls (129.97,149.85) and (126.73,153.21) .. (126.73,156.72) .. controls (126.73,160.23) and (129.97,163.59) .. (135.69,166) .. controls (141.06,168.07) and (148,168.92) .. (154.74,168.32) .. controls (157.37,168.32) and (159.5,167.28) .. (159.5,166) .. controls (159.5,164.72) and (157.37,163.68) .. (154.74,163.68) .. controls (148,163.08) and (141.06,163.93) .. (135.69,166) .. controls (129.97,168.41) and (126.73,171.77) .. (126.73,175.28) .. controls (126.73,178.79) and (129.97,182.15) .. (135.69,184.56) .. controls (141.06,186.63) and (148,187.48) .. (154.74,186.88) .. controls (157.37,186.88) and (159.5,185.84) .. (159.5,184.56) .. controls (159.5,183.28) and (157.37,182.24) .. (154.74,182.24) .. controls (148,181.64) and (141.06,182.49) .. (135.69,184.56) .. controls (128.81,187.25) and (126.01,191.72) .. (128.64,195.82) .. controls (131.27,199.92) and (138.79,202.82) .. (147.6,203.12) -- (147.6,224) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8016455039717147] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (147.6,129) -- (174.5,129) ;
\draw [shift={(177.5,129)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9865755377082461] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (177.5,129) -- (197.5,129) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da45669051030988794] 
\draw [line width=2.25]    (147.6,68) -- (147.6,258) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3100751920943625] 
\draw    (119.6,75) -- (119.51,117.14) ;
\draw [shift={(119.5,120.14)}, rotate = 270.12] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7289527594289138] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (147.6,203.12) -- (191.5,203) ;

% Text Node
\draw (96,77.54) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$I_{P}$};
% Text Node
\draw (176,104.54) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$I_{S}$};
% Text Node
\draw (70,46.14) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Main Primary Conductor};
% Text Node
\draw (178,156.14) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Secondary Winding};
% Text Node
\draw (100,262.14) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Circuit Symbol};
% Text Node
\draw (89,156.14) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {C.T.};


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A typical circuit C.T.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]